# Storing the IP of EC2 instance using Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am new to Ansible and I wrote a Ansible playbook which will spinup EC2 instances. I want to save the public IP or DNS name of the created instance, so that I can perform other operations on it.

```
tasks:

  - name: Create a security group
    local_action: 
      module: ec2_group
      name: "{{ security_group }}"
      description: Security Group for webserver Servers
      region: "{{ region }}"
      rules:
        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 80
          to_port: 80
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

      rules_egress:
        - proto: all
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
    register: basic_firewall

  - name: Launch the new EC2 Instance
    local_action: ec2 
                  group={{ security_group }} 
                  instance_type={{ instance_type}} 
                  image={{ image }} 
                  wait=true 
                  region={{ region }} 
                  keypair={{ keypair }}
                  count={{count}}
    register: ec2

 This playbook runs successfully and creates 1 instance on EC2. But need to save the IP or DNS name to hosts file for future use
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ec2` variable that is the result of the ec2 module execution should contain all the needed information about the created instances. You can inspect the contents of this variable by using [the `debug` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/debug_module.html) like in the example below:

```
- debug:
    var: result
```

There surely will be a lot of information in there including the IP and the DNS name of your instance which you can use in later module execution.

As a matter of fact, there is an example in the [ec2 ansible module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_module.html) documentation that does almost exactly what you need:

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
    groupname: launched
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Above code adds the IP addresses of all created instances to the current inventory. In your case you just need to change `add_host` to, something like [`lineinfile`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html) (or [`template`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html)) module:

```
- name: Ensure the added instance is in /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    regexp: '^.* created_host'
    line: "{{ item.public_ip }} created_host"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Just make sure that this task gets executed on the proper host by a user that actually can change `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after adding the mentioned lines to my playbook.